# c inotify not always triggering event for specific file

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* p;
    struct inotify_event *event;
    int sd, gd, fd;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    fd = inotify_init();
    if( fd < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    gd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/interactive", IN_MODIFY);
    sd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/sys/class/graphics/fb0/show_blank_event", IN_MODIFY);


    for(;;) {
        read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN); //Thread block here. Waits for event triggering
        event = (struct inotify_event *) buffer; //Get the event

        if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
            if(event->wd == sd) {
                printf("Handle screen event\n");
                //pthread_create(&handle_screen_event, NULL, handleScreenEvent, (void*)NULL);
            }

            if(event->wd == gd) {
                printf("Handle gov event\n"); //This is not triggered after some time of being in standby (screen off) mode. Yet the screen event trigger is always fired
                //pthread_create(&handle_gov_event, NULL, handleGovEvent, (void*)NULL);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So here is the code. I call `inotify_add_watch()` but after a few minutes with the screen off the "handle gov event" never triggers again. "Handle screen event" always triggers though. I have no idea why its behaving this way. I did add a check for `IN_IGNORE` to see if the file was getting deleted but it never triggered. I just don't understand how one is working but not the other.

I am running this on an android device. Galaxy S7.

Thanks all.

Comment: You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want help.  In the meantime, you can add debug code to emit things like the actual return value from `read()` - which you're currently ignoring - and the entire contents of the `event` structure.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have edited my question. This should be all the code needed. Hopefully someone can help. It feels like it has to do with the device entering deep sleep, but it doesn't make sense to me as to why the screen on event is still working. Or as to why it doesn't trigger even after the screen comes on and I `echo` values to the governor directory.